# How do I deploy an Octopress blog to an existing gh-pages static site?

Tags: github, jekyll, octopress, github-pages

So deploying to a `gh-pages` branch on Github with Octopress is relatively simple. It is spelled [out here](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/).

However, I already have a static site hosted on my `gh-pages` branch (and the source stored in the master branch).

So how do I keep my static site, while deploying my blog to just either a `blog.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/blog` where I am using `gh-pages` to manage both the Octopress blog and the static site for `mydomain.com`.

I also checked out [these instructions](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/template/#landing_page) for moving the blog to something to like `blog/index.html`...but it seems like it doesn't quite allow me to fully separate my static site from the blog. Seems like the styles may overlap and lots of other drama. I would rather keep them separate.

Is this even possible?

If not...is there a workaround to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the best way to do this, and I have done a thorough [write-up about it here](http://www.marcgayle.com/2013/09/21/deploying-octopress-blog-to-an-existing-gh-pages-static-site/).

Hope that helps anyone else that struggles with it - the way I have.

Answer (score 0):

By default Octopress publishes your blog to *User or Organization* Github Pages. I think you'd need to deploy your blog to *Project* Github Pages instead. See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) for the description of the difference.

This would mean that you would have another branch called **gh-pages**.

- Your existing static site would be on the **master** branch and would deploy to **username.github.io**.
- Your blog would be on the **gh-pages** branch and would deploy to **username.github.io/projectname**

This sounds quite hopeful, and it may that with some carefully configured CNAME records, it may be enough.

**Edit**

There are instructions for deploying to Github project pages in the section *With Github Project pages (gh-pages)* on the [deployment instructions page](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/).

A possible alternative would be switch the locations. That is, leave the blog in the **master** branch (and deploy it to **username.github.io**) and put your existing static site in a *Project* page at **username.github.io/projectname**. Then you can setup CNAME records so that blog.mydomain.com and site.mydomain.com point to the right places.

Comment: The issue I have with this is that the instructions are centered around `jekyll` and not `octopress` which is what I am using.

Comment: Octopress is built with Jekyll which is why the instructions ought to work, but you would probably have to modify the Octopress source if you go that route. Did you manage to get it published to a project page first? I think there's a good chance you don't have to make any changes anyway.

Comment: Actually I just realised, there are instructions on [this page](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) in the section _With Github Project pages (gh-pages)_. So you shouldn't need to modify any source.

Comment: Yeh...this is the default way to do any octopress installation. What I was looking for is if I have a static HTML site published on `gh-pages`, how do I then publish the octopress blog to that same `gh-pages` branch. I have since figured it out - so you don't have to stress about it. I will write up an answer shortly.